# HTTPPost Call through application/x-protobuf Format Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, protocol-buffers

I am using application/x-protobuf format with WebAPi. My Get Request is working fine but when I want to send Post my request (like city data) is not hit the target api action. Please have a look at where I am going wrong 
[image: Web project]

[image: WebAPi]

[image: My Cofig Route]